# How to do clean validation in Angular templates

Tags: angular

I have just started writing some validation logic in a form and its already getting messy, I haven't even included all the rules. The textbox needs to be red if there are errors as well as a message under the box:

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" [class.input-validation-error]="!dataForm.get('name').valid && dataForm.get('name').touched">
  <div *ngIf="dataForm.get('name').hasError('required') && dataForm.get('name').touched" class="validation-error">
    The product name is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this standard with Angular forms or am I doing the validation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is taken from [validating reactive forms article](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-reactive-form-validation) written by Lukas Marx.

> Using a reactive form, we can define form and it's element with
>   validation as shown in following example. You can also create a custom
>   validator. Use [this link](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/) to know more about it.
>
> ```
> /*component */
> testForm: FormGroup;
> constructor() {
>   this.testForm = this.createFormGroup();
> }
>
> createFormGroup() {
>  return new FormGroup({
>   name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), 
>   email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]), 
>   ....
>  });
>
> }
> ```
>
> The template:
>
> ```
>  <form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> 
>     Name: 
>     <input formControlName="name"> 
>     Email: 
>     <input formControlName="email"> 
>     <button type="submit"> Save </button> 
>  </form>
> ```
>
> We need to be able to check the status of each form-field. We can
>   define getter functions in our component (It will make things easy).
>   i.e.
>
> ```
>  get name() {
>     return this.testForm.get('name'); 
>    }
>
>  get email() {
>    return this.testForm.get('email); 
>   }
> ```
>
> Finally we can adjust our template to show error messages:
>
> ```
>  Name: 
>     <input formControlName="name"> 
>     <span *ngIf="name.invalid && name.errors.required"> Name is required </span>
>
>     Email: 
>     <input formControlName="email"> 
>     <span *ngIf="email.invalid && email.errors.required"> Email is required </span>
>     <span *ngIf="email.invalid && !email.errors.required && email.errors.email"> Invalid Email </span>
> ```
>
> The above html will show error message on page load itself which we
>   don't require; in order to prevent it and show errors only if the user
>   touched the control, we can check if control is dirty or got touched
>   (on mobile).
>
> ```
>  Name: 
>   <input ...... >
>   <span *ngIf="name.dirty || name.touched) && name.invalid && name.errors.required"> 
>   Name is required. 
>   </span>
> ```
>
> If showing a plain error message is not enough, we can also adjust the
>   appearance of each form-control using CSS. For that, angular
>   automatically assigns some classes ot each control, depending of its
>   status.  For example, if we wanted invalid controls to appear red and
>   valid ones to be green, we could use a style like below:
>
> ```
> .ng-valid {background-color: green; }
> .ng-invalid:not(form) {background-color: red}
> ```

You can read [the article](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-reactive-form-validation) for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use get method,

```
get name() {
 return this.dateForm.get('name');
}
```

and In html simply use,

```
 *ngIf="name.hasError('required') && name.touched"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like

```
        <form class="form" role="form" name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"
                       formControlName="email"
                       minlength="5"
                       maxlength="50"
                       pattern="^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.+]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)@([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)[\\.]([a-zA-Z]{2,9})*$">
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['email'].dirty && form.controls['email'].invalid">
                <p class="error-text" *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.required">
                    Your email is required.
                </p>
                <p class="error-text" *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.minlength">
                    Your email is required to be at least 5 characters.
                </p>
                <p class="error-text" *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.maxlength">
                    Your email cannot be longer than 50 characters.
                </p>
                <p class="error-text" *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.pattern">
                    Your email needs to be a correct email address.
                </p>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="mt-4 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

you can target invalid input element with css

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
 border:1px solid red;
 background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
 border:1px solid red;
 background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: i like this one

Answer (score 0):

As @malbarnawi suggested, you could try with CSS. But extend it to both form control and validation error.

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" [class.input-validation-error]="!dataForm.get('name').valid && dataForm.get('name').touched">
  <div class="validation-error">
    The product name is required
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your component css:

```
.validation-error {
  display: none;
}
.ng-invalid.ng-touched + .validation-error {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-validation-styling?file=src/app/app.component.css).